# Maintain saml IDP session as long as there is user-activity in the SP

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I looking for a SAML2 way to maintain the session on the IdP as long as there is activity on the SP.
Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: the SP session should only be as long as the attribute NotOnOrAfter value

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to the protocol that makes promises about session maintenance. I suppose that a set of partners could come to an agreement on sessioning, and maybe even use the Attribute Query binding for keeping the session alive at the IdP, but, it takes significant coordination, and Attribute Query isn't a common binding.

In essence, you'll need the SP to shorten their SSO session Idle/Max Timeouts to shorter than yours. I daresay, it may be an inconvenience to do so, but maybe it will end up being workable.